# JavaScriptSerializer : Unable to deserialize object containing HashSet field

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize an instance of the following class from a JSON string using JavaScriptSerializer:

```
public class Filter
{
    public HashSet<int> DataSources { get; set;  }
}
```

Here is the code I am trying out:

```
        Filter f = new Filter();

        f.DataSources = new HashSet<int>(){1,2};

        string json = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(f);         

        var g= (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<Filter>(json);
```

It errors out with the following message:

> Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Int32]'.

Apparently, the serializer is unable to distinguish between a list and set from JSON representation. What is the solution to this?

Note : I would prefer avoiding the use of external libraries due to constraints at work.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the solution to this?

Use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/). This code works...

```
Filter f = new Filter();

f.DataSources = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2 };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f);

var g = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Filter>(json);
```

**EDIT**

`DataContractJsonSerializer` seems to work too...

```
DataContractJsonSerializer dcjs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Filter));
var g2 = dcjs.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json))) as Filter;
```

Comment: Thanks! But my work requires me to avoid using external libraries. Any solution using .net's in-built libraries would be of great help

Comment: @I4V `DataContractJsonSerializer` works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simple NOT so great solution, but it works.

```
var dataList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<int>>(returnData);
var data = new HashSet<int>(dataList);
```